# Reverse bits of a unsigned integer

Tags: java, integer, bit-manipulation

The below two code is the method can invert the bits of an unsigned 32 bits integer. But What's the difference of the two code below?
Why the first code is wrong and the second code is correct.
I can't see the difference of these two.

```
public int reverseBits(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        result = result << 1 | (n & (1 << i));
    }
    return result;
}
public int reverseBits(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        result = result << 1 | ((n >> i) & 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code is wrong, because it extracts given bit and puts it in the same position of the resulting number. Suppose you are on iteration `i = 5`. Then `n & (1 << 5)` = `n & 32` which is either 0 or `0b100000`. The intention is to put the one-bit to the lowest position, but when performing | operation it actually puts it to the same position #5. On the consequent iterations you move this bit even higher, so you practically have all the bits or'ed at the highest bit position.

Please note that there are more effective algorithms to reverse bits like one implemented in standard JDK [`Integer.reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverse-int-) method:

```
public static int reverse(int i) {
    // HD, Figure 7-1
    i = (i & 0x55555555) << 1 | (i >>> 1) & 0x55555555;
    i = (i & 0x33333333) << 2 | (i >>> 2) & 0x33333333;
    i = (i & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4 | (i >>> 4) & 0x0f0f0f0f;
    i = (i << 24) | ((i & 0xff00) << 8) |
        ((i >>> 8) & 0xff00) | (i >>> 24);
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with whether the bit being grabbed from n is being stored in the rightmost bit of the result or being stored back into the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `n` is 4 (for example).
Then when `i` is 2, the expression `(n & (1 << i))`
becomes `(4 & (1 << 2))`, which should equal `4 & 4`, so it evaluates to 4.
But the expression `((n >> i) & 1)` 
becomes `((4 >> 2) & 1)`, which should equal `1 & 1`,  so it evaluates to 1.

The two expressions do not have the same result.

But both versions of the function try to use those results in the exact same way, so the two versions of the function do not have the same result.